# Why a specific folder isn't accessible even if my program is executed as admin?

Tags: vb.net, minecraft

**Hi people!**

So right now I'm making a Minecraft Launcher, but I have a problem. I need to list every libraries in the .minecraft libraries folder, but the launcher can't access it even if it's executed as administrator.

Here is the code that fails :

```
Try
    FileList = File.ReadAllLines(AppDataDir & "\libraries").ToList()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

The FileList variable :

```
Dim FileList As New List(Of String)
```

I need to make it a list of string because of this code :

```
Dim GameLibs As String = Nothing
For i = 0 To FileList.Count - 1
    GameLibs += FileList.Item(i) + ";" + Environment.NewLine()
Next
```

So now I'm stuck with this problem, but I can't understand it since it works nicely with any other folder.

Oh and, the `AppDataDir` variable is just the .minecraft directory.

**Any help would be great! Thanks if you tried to help me anyway.**

Comment: With this: `FileList = File.ReadAllLines(AppDataDir & "\libraries").ToList()`, you're tying to read the content (all lines) of a text file, but you're passing a Directory path. Maybe, you wanted to list the files inside that `libraries` folder? See: [Directory.GetFiles()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles) or [Directory.EnumerateFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles).

Comment: I don't want to do EnumerateFiles since I want to list all files of the folder, and Directory.GetFiles returns nothing :

``For i As Integer = 0 To FileList.Count - 1
        GameLibs = FileList(i)
Next``

then I did this :

``MsgBox(GameLibs)``

But it returns nothing as I said earlier. And I edited the ``FileList = File.ReadAllLines`` to ``FileList = Directory.GetFiles`` and ``Dim FileList As New List(Of String)`` to ``Dim FileList As String()``.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just missed the file name and its extension, try to add that line like this one:

```
    FileList = File.ReadAllLines(AppDataDir & "\libraries.txt").ToList()
```

I hope that helps.

^_^

Comment: No, it's a folder I want to access, but still thx for your help.

Comment: U R Welcome ^_^